# Inserting an empty row dynamically in Horizontal Recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm just one step to getting this dynamic layout work for me but I just cant figure out what I'm doing wrong.
I have the following string: 
AAA__AB/
_AAAAAA/
_AAABBB/

I'm supposed to convert the above strings to a rooms layout whereby:
A - Represents available rooms
B - Represents booked rooms
_ - Represents a space
/ - Represents a new line

I have been following this tutorial [Dynamic bus seats layout](https://github.com/varunjohn/Booking-Seats-Layout-Sample) to try and make an app that can create Apartment rooms layout dynamically in **RecyclerView**.
I have a horizontally oriented recyclerview as the parent recyclerView. I have an adapter and a data source from a webserver.
Everything is working fine apart from the NEW_LINE feature which is supposed to force the recyclerview add a new line/row so that the rest of the views may align themselves in the new row/line
Please help

**The following is what I get**
[The way my layout looks like as at now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSGau.png)

**The following is what I want**
[The intended layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8Bws.png)

**The Main Activity.java**

```
...rest of the code
//Displaying the rooms and trying to make the layout
private void display_rooms_details(){

    ArrayList house_rooms;
    house_rooms=new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < rooms_list.size(); i++)
    {
        if(rooms_list.get(i).getType()==0){
            house_rooms.add(new Decode_rooms(Decode_rooms.AVAILABLE_ROOMS, rooms_list.get(i).getRoom_type(), rooms_list.get(i).getRoom_number(), rooms_list.get(i).getRoom_name(), rooms_list.get(i).getRoom_symbol(), rooms_list.get(i).getRoom_tenant()));
        }
        if(rooms_list.get(i).getType()==1){
            house_rooms.add(new Decode_rooms(Decode_rooms.BOOKED_ROOMS, rooms_list.get(i).getRoom_type(), rooms_list.get(i).getRoom_number(), rooms_list.get(i).getRoom_name(), rooms_list.get(i).getRoom_symbol(), rooms_list.get(i).getRoom_tenant()));
        }
        if(rooms_list.get(i).getType()==2){
            house_rooms.add(new Decode_rooms(Decode_rooms.NEW_LINE, rooms_list.get(i).getRoom_type(), rooms_list.get(i).getRoom_number(), rooms_list.get(i).getRoom_name(), rooms_list.get(i).getRoom_symbol(), rooms_list.get(i).getRoom_tenant()));
        }
        if(rooms_list.get(i).getType()==3){
            house_rooms.add(new Decode_rooms(Decode_rooms.SPACE, rooms_list.get(i).getRoom_type(), rooms_list.get(i).getRoom_number(), rooms_list.get(i).getRoom_name(), rooms_list.get(i).getRoom_symbol(), rooms_list.get(i).getRoom_tenant()));
        }

    }
    RecyclerView myrv= findViewById(R.id.recycleview_item_list);
    Adapter_display_rooms myAdapter= new Adapter_display_rooms(this,house_rooms);
    myrv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, OrientationHelper.HORIZONTAL,false));
    myrv.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    myrv.setAdapter(myAdapter);

}
```

**Adapter_display_rooms**

```
 public class Adapter_display_rooms extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>{

    //Declare context and the class with our list
    private static Context mContext;
    int total_types;
    private static ArrayList<Decode_rooms> rooms_list; //Our data class... this one contains the get and set methods to decode the data for us

    //Available rooms layout class
    public static class ActualRoomsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        CardView cardview;
        TextView txtType;
        ImageView image;

        public ActualRoomsViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            this.cardview= itemView.findViewById(R.id.layout_available_rooms);
            this.image =  itemView.findViewById(R.id.room_icon);
            this.txtType = itemView.findViewById(R.id.room_name);
        }
    }


    //New Line layout class
    public static class NewLineViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        LinearLayout linearlayout;

        public NewLineViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            this.linearlayout =  itemView.findViewById(R.id.layout_newline);
        }
    }


    //New Line layout class
    public static class AddSpaceViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView txtType;

        public AddSpaceViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            this.txtType =  itemView.findViewById(R.id.add_space);
        }
    }



    //END OF VIEWHOLDER CLASSES

    //The Class Constructor
    public Adapter_display_rooms(Context mContext, ArrayList<Decode_rooms> rooms_list) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.rooms_list = rooms_list;
        total_types=rooms_list.size();
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view;
        switch (viewType) {
            case Decode_rooms.AVAILABLE_ROOMS:
                view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_rooms_layout_listview_rooms, parent, false);
                return new ActualRoomsViewHolder(view);
            case Decode_rooms.BOOKED_ROOMS:
                view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_rooms_layout_listview_rooms, parent, false);
                return new ActualRoomsViewHolder(view);
            case Decode_rooms.NEW_LINE:
                view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_rooms_layout_listview_newline, parent, false);
                return new NewLineViewHolder(view);
            case Decode_rooms.SPACE:
                view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_rooms_layout_listview_space, parent, false);
                return new AddSpaceViewHolder(view);
        }
        return null;

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {

        switch (rooms_list.get(position).type) {
            case 0:
                return Decode_rooms.AVAILABLE_ROOMS;
            case 1:
                return Decode_rooms.BOOKED_ROOMS;
            case 2:
                return Decode_rooms.NEW_LINE;
            case 3:
                return Decode_rooms.SPACE;
            default:
                return -1;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final Decode_rooms object = rooms_list.get(position);
        if (object != null) {
            switch (object.type) {
                case Decode_rooms.AVAILABLE_ROOMS:
                    ((ActualRoomsViewHolder) holder).image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_seats_book);
                    ((ActualRoomsViewHolder) holder).txtType.setText(object.getRoom_number());
                    ((ActualRoomsViewHolder) holder).cardview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            Intent intent=new Intent(mContext, Available_room_details.class);
                            intent.putExtra("room_number",object.getRoom_number());
                            intent.putExtra("room_name",object.getRoom_name());
                            intent.putExtra("room_type",object.getRoom_type());
                            mContext.startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    });
                    ((ActualRoomsViewHolder) holder).cardview.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                            //Creating the instance of PopupMenu
                            PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(mContext,v);
                            //Inflating the Popup using xml file
                            popup.getMenuInflater()
                                    .inflate(R.menu.menu_available_room_options, popup.getMenu());

                            //registering popup with OnMenuItemClickListener
                            popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                                    Toast.makeText(
                                            mContext,
                                            "You Clicked : " + item.getTitle(),
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                                    ).show();
                                    return true;
                                }
                            });

                            popup.show(); //showing popup menu
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
                    break;
                case Decode_rooms.BOOKED_ROOMS:
                    ((ActualRoomsViewHolder) holder).image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_seats_booked);
                    ((ActualRoomsViewHolder) holder).txtType.setText(object.getRoom_number());
                    ((ActualRoomsViewHolder) holder).cardview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            Intent intent=new Intent(mContext, Booked_room_details.class);
                            intent.putExtra("room_number",object.getRoom_number());
                            intent.putExtra("room_name",object.getRoom_name());
                            intent.putExtra("room_type",object.getRoom_type());
                            mContext.startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    });
                    ((ActualRoomsViewHolder) holder).cardview.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                            //Creating the instance of PopupMenu
                            PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(mContext,v);
                            //Inflating the Popup using xml file
                            popup.getMenuInflater()
                                    .inflate(R.menu.menu_booked_room_options, popup.getMenu());

                            //registering popup with OnMenuItemClickListener
                            popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                                    Toast.makeText(
                                            mContext,
                                            "You Clicked : " + item.getTitle(),
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                                    ).show();
                                    return true;
                                }
                            });

                            popup.show(); //showing popup menu
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
                    break;
                case Decode_rooms.NEW_LINE:

                    break;
                case Decode_rooms.SPACE:
                    ((AddSpaceViewHolder) holder).txtType.setText("Space "+object.getRoom_number());
                    break;
                default:
                    ((ActualRoomsViewHolder) holder).txtType.setText("Default "+object.getRoom_number());
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return rooms_list.size();
    }
```

**Decode rooms java**

```
    public class Decode_rooms {
    //Aid the custom adapter in inflating different types of layouts
    public static final int AVAILABLE_ROOMS = 0;
    public static final int BOOKED_ROOMS = 1;
    public static final int NEW_LINE = 2;
    public static final int SPACE = 3;

    String room_type,room_number,room_name,room_symbol,room_tenant;
    public int type; //This variable will hold the type of data i.e THE ROOM SYMBOL .. It'll tell the adapter the layout to inflate


    public Decode_rooms(int type,String room_type, String room_number, String room_name, String room_symbol, String room_tenant) {
        this.type = type;
        this.room_type = room_type;
        this.room_number = room_number;
        this.room_name = room_name;
        this.room_symbol = room_symbol;
        this.room_tenant = room_tenant;
    }

    //The setter methods

    public void setType(int type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public void setRoom_type(String room_type) {
        this.room_type = room_type;
    }

    public void setRoom_number(String room_number) {
        this.room_number = room_number;
    }

    public void setRoom_name(String room_name) {
        this.room_name = room_name;
    }

    public void setRoom_symbol(String room_symbol) {
        this.room_symbol = room_symbol;
    }

    public void setRoom_tenant(String room_tenant) {
        this.room_tenant = room_tenant;
    }

    //The getter methods

    public int getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public String getRoom_type() {
        return room_type;
    }

    public String getRoom_number() {
        return room_number;
    }

    public String getRoom_name() {
        return room_name;
    }

    public String getRoom_symbol() {
        return room_symbol;
    }

    public String getRoom_tenant() {
        return room_tenant;
    }
}
```

**Parent xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/recyclerview" />



</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**The recyclerView**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycleview_item_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:background="@color/blue"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**The Card view / Individual row item for rooms**

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout_available_rooms"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/room_width"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/room_height"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/roomGaping"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/room_icon"
            android:background="@color/black"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/room_width"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/room_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#2d2d2d"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            android:text="Room Name"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

**The new line layout**

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout_newline"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/room_height"
    android:background="@color/grey_background"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks sir, I'm currently working on it using your solution.. I will give feedback asap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is GridLayoutManager with column count of maximum of length of all rows. (You can set it as lcm of length of all inputs)

Iterate through each input and set column span as required. Let me know if anything is not clear.

Edit: Adding sample code

`TestActivity.java`

```
public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

        final String[] inputs = new String[3];
        inputs[0] = "AAA__AB/";
        inputs[1] = "_AAAAAA/";
        inputs[2] = "_ABB/";

        final StringBuilder sb  = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i =0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
            sb.append(inputs[i]);
        }

        String[] modifiedInput = sb.toString().split("/");

        final int lcm = getLcm(modifiedInput);

        GridLayoutManager manager = new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), lcm);
        manager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
            @Override
            public int getSpanSize(int i) {
                if(sb.toString().charAt(i) == '/') {
                    return lcm;
                }
                else {
                    int index = 0;
                    for(int j = 0; j< inputs.length; j++) {
                        if(i < index+inputs[j].length()) {
                            if(inputs[j].contains("/")) return lcm / (inputs[j].length()-1);
                            else return lcm / inputs[j].length();
                        }
                        else {
                            index += inputs[j].length();
                        }
                    }
                    throw new IllegalStateException("Wrong index");
                }
            }
        });


        List<String> inputDataList = new ArrayList<>();
        String flatInputData = sb.toString();
        for(int i = 0; i < flatInputData.length(); i++) {
            inputDataList.add(String.valueOf(flatInputData.charAt(i)));
        }
        Adapter adapter = new Adapter(inputDataList);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);

    }

    private int getLcm(String[] modifiedInputs) {
        int lcm = modifiedInputs[0].length();
        for(int i = 1; i< modifiedInputs.length; i++) {
            lcm = lcm(lcm, modifiedInputs[i].length());
        }

        return lcm;
    }

    public static  int lcm(int a, int b) {
        return a/gcd(a,b) * b;
    }

    public static int gcd(int a, int b){
        if (a<b) return gcd(b,a);
        if (a%b==0) return b;
        else return gcd(b, a%b);
    }
}
```

`Adapter.java`

```
public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.ViewHolder> {

    public List<String> data;

    public Adapter(List<String> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        return new ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, viewGroup, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        String text = data.get(i);
        if(!text.equals("/"))
            viewHolder.textView.setText(text);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if(data == null) {
            return 0;
        }
        else {
            return data.size();
        }
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView textView;
        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textView = itemView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Kindly elaborate by use of code ..maybe using the sample string I attached. Epecially on how to dynamically determine the number of columns given that the app will be having different rooms layouts with different lengths

Comment: great! you can also approve this answer so that others can see the solution.

Comment: I have upvoted it but being a new contributor, its not recording ... Much appreciated tho' @rahul-kumar

Comment: The code works fine but sometimes it crashes all of a sudden. I checked logcat n the following is the error:

java.lang.ArithmeticException: divide by zero

Other times it crashes with error:

Wrong index

I dont know exactly what is causing this or whether its my code... I simply dont get where the errors appear. Then other times its just fine without changing any part of the code

Comment: there might be some issue while division, check where any division is happening and add a log to see if the denominator is zero